# SQL 2008 Replication

Tags: database-replication

I have replicated two database in SQL2008.

The last two days the distribution database from publisher server changed to Suspect Mode and the replication process is down.

I read a lot from Google and tried to repair, but without success.

During my repairing process, the Distribution Database is has changed to Emergency mode.

Can anyone please kindly suggest any solutions?

Comment: Ohhh yes you can :P

Comment: Please let us know more about your replication-setup (snapshot / transactional / merge).
What can read out of the log-files?
Have a look at tempdb, is it healthy?
How long is the system up and running (days/weeks/months) or more?
How did you try to repair?
and last but not least, is there free disk capacity on the disk where the distribution database lies.
good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the books available on the subject: http://oreilly.com/pub/topic/sqlserver

Particularly: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780735626041/

Try to make your question title more specific - this will get more attention and hopefully more answers to choose from!